# how do i add page curl effect in ImageView and also that ImageView should be zoom able and should be scroll able when its zoomed

Tags: android, swipe-gesture, zooming, page-curl

I need page curl effect for android.

I checked the following [links](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)

Both are working fine with limited images if I add more images its crash application.

And for Zoom I checked following [link](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

but TouchImageView and pagecurl both not working together.

Is there any solution for use page curl and TouchImageview together for 90+ images resources in efficient way? 
or any other libs which provide curl with zoom functionality together in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [PageCurlWithZoom](https://github.com/DeveloperMayur/PageCurlWithZoom)

solution for use TouchImageview in layout with 90+ images resources in efficient way and Page Curl Effect with bitmap memory management.